# Continuous vs Discrete system simulation in Python

Tags: control-engineering

Normally, when you discretize continuous system with zoh method, your continuous system output with the corresponding discrete inputs passed through zero-order hold should be the same at sampling instants. But here in my code it is not the same, but I can't understand why? Here we have a second order system, and I apply discrete PID control to the discrete system and simulate it in for loop. Then I take the discrete input values and for simulating continuous time system output I accumulate (many) shifted and weighted (by discrete input values) step responses of the continuous system to get the output. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import control.matlab as cn


sys = cn.tf([1, 1], [1, 4, 5])
Ts = 0.01
sysd = cn.sample_system(sys, Ts)

print(sysd)

# prints:
#
# 0.009851 z - 0.009753
# ---------------------
# z^2 - 1.96 z + 0.9608

ref = np.ones(1100)
Kp = 10.
Kd = 1.
Ki = 1.

y = []
y.append(0.)
u = []
u.append(Kp * (ref[0] - y[0] ) + Ki*(ref[0] - y[0] ) + Kd*(ref[0] - y[0]))
y.append(0.009851*u[0])
Acc_Intg = ref[0] - y[0]   # Accumulator for Sum of errrors for Integral term Ki.


for i in np.arange(1, 110):
    Acc_Intg = Acc_Intg + ref[i] - y[i]
    u.append(Kp * (ref[i] - y[i]) + Kd * ((ref[i] - y[i]) - (ref[i - 1] - y[i - 1])) + Ki * Acc_Intg)
    y.append(y[i]*1.96 - y[i-1]*0.9608 + u[i]*0.009851 - u[i-1]*0.009753)


T = np.arange(0, 0.8, 0.01)
u = np.array(u)
yc, TT = cn.step(sys, T)
yc = yc*u[0]
for i in np.arange(1, T.size -5):
    yaux, TT = cn.step(sys, T[0:(T.size - i)])
    yc[i:] = yc[i:] +  (u[i] - u[i-1]) * yaux


y = np.array(y)
plt.plot(np.arange(0, y.size * 0.01 - 0.0000001, 0.01), y)
plt.plot(T, yc)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show **in math** the algorithm that you are attempting to realize in Python.  That will help us to determine if it is your underlying algorithm, or the code, that is at fault.

Comment: Sorry, but I moved the question to this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411422/continuous-vs-discrete-linear-system-simulation-python. And it was a simple rounding problem.